# Replace file belonging to an installed RPM with a different RPM using YUM

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, package-management, rpm

How to replace a file belonging to an installed RPM with a different RPM (a hotfix RPM) that includes the same file, using YUM.

YUM does not provide the --replacefiles option (available in the rpm command) and hence fails due to the conflict between the 2 packages containing the same file.

Is there an option in YUM that will address this ? Or a workaround to do such installations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the rpms and do the install with the rpm command and the local files.  yumdownloader is part of yum-utils on RHEL and makes it easy to download rpms from a yum repo.

Or, you can run the rpm command directly using urls for the RPMs instead of local copies of the RPMs.